# Pegar o id de um Panel que esta sendo criado dinamicamente

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Estou criando varias panel dinamicamente conforme a quantidade de cadastros em uma tabela do banco e dados:

```
pnlBtn := TPanel.Create(Self); // Cria o um Panel
      pnlBtn.Parent := pnlMesas; // seta pnlMesa como parente

      sTop := FloatToStr(rTop);
      sLeft := FloatToStr(rLeft);

      //Posição do Panel
      pnlBtn.Top := StrToInt(sTop);
      pnlBtn.Left := StrToInt(sLeft);

      //Tamanho do Panel
      pnlBtn.Width := 103;
      pnlBtn.Height := 50;

      //Informações Gerais do panel
      pnlBtn.Name := 'pnlMesaComanda' + intToStr(iContador);
```

e queria criar varias label dentro deste panel dinamico com as informações cadastradas no banco porém como eu pego o id deste panel que criei dinamicamente para colocar no parent?

exemplo:

```
lblCod := TLabel.Create(Self);
lblCod.Parent := 'pnlMesaComanda' + intToStr(iContador);
```

alguém pode me ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No delhpi nao tem essa questão de id, mas o nome dos componentes servem com identificador. Então o Nome dele vai ser o id, ou pode criar uma variável dentro dele com o para ser o ID.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado